# Qual è la regola grammaticale nell'uso di "stampa" nella espressione "le conferenze stampa"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Perché non si dice "Le conferenze stampa" e non si dice "Le conferenze di/da/della/delle stampa/e" o non si dice "Le conferenze stampe". Qual'è il ruolo grammatico di "stampa" in questa espressione. Mi ricordo che avevo visto altre espressioni del genere ma non ricordo cosa c'erano esattamente.

Può fare alcuni esempi nel quale un sostantivo succede un altro sostantivo senza nessun proposizione  e costruisce una espressione che implica un significato nuovo. Mica in tutte queste espressioni si identifica il primo sostantivo come quello che cambia grammaticamente facendo plurale o aggiungendo aggettivi(per esempio. "Le conferenze stampa dure che stavo guardando")

Comment: Invece 'le conferenze stampa', che sono le conferenze alle quali sono invitati i giornalisti,  si dice. Perché pensi che non si dica? What's unclear?

Comment: A better example than the dubious *le conferenze stampa dure che stavo guardando* would be useful.

Comment: @Johnny, did you mean «Perché si dice "Le conferenze stampa"...»?

Comment: Very interesting question. Similarly, one would also say "comunicati stampa".

Comment: Titolo della domanda in inglese, post in italiano, commenti misti, risposte ancora in inglese. Che confusione!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such phrases are nominal syntagms in which a preposition has been lost and are actually quite common in Italian: just think *posto letto*, *pesce martello*, *carro attrezzi*, *decreto legge*, *pausa caffè*, *angolo cottura*, *sala professori*, *parola chiave* and so on. They are a special case of the more general process of composition, which explains the formation of many words from simpler words (*portalettere*, *capoclasse*, *altopiano*, ...).

In the plural and with adjectives, they behave just like they would if the missing preposition were there: *l'angusto angolo (per la) cottura*, *gli angusti angoli (per la) cottura*.

Answer (score 3):

The [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stampa/) says that in this case *stampa* is still a noun and means:

> Con valore collettivo, i giornalisti, come categoria professionale o operatori del settore

similarly to the English *the press*.

Another examples is

> sala della s. (o comunem. sala stampa), sede permanente o allestita in occasione di determinate manifestazioni, presso la quale i giornalisti possono scrivere e trasmettere i loro servizî ai rispettivi giornali;

Note that under the lemma [*conferenza*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conferenza/) they write it in hyphenated form

> In partic., conferenza-stampa (plur. conferenze-stampa), intervista concessa da uomini politici, scrittori, attori, cantanti e, in genere, persone molto note, ai rappresentanti della stampa.